# JSON validation giving success even when required field is missing

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Please explain as to why this json is not giving validation error against the schema:

**Schema**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properites": {
    "address": {
      "type": "array",
      "items":{
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "port": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "interface": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "maskLength": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "ip",
            "port",
            "interface",
            "maskLength"
          ]
        }
    }
  },
      "required": [
        "address"
  ]
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
        "address": [
            {
                "ip": 1,
                "port": 8305
            },
            {
                "ip": "2405:200:1413:100::5:cc",
                "port": "8205",
                "interface": "eno1",
                "maskLength": 112
            },
            {
                "ip": 2,
                "port": 8105,
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm testing this on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and it gives validation successful which I don't understand. **interface** and **maskLength** are required fields as per the schema and these are missing from some array elements. Also, the type of "ip" is string in schema but in the json, integer type is also being accepted. Why is this json not being rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*facepalm*

I had misspelled properties as properites!! Damn!